# TypeError: can't convert Post into Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I'm using Rails 3 and will_paginate. Pagination works fine in my Posts controller but in my Tags controller I get an error on the second Tag id. Here's the error:

```
TypeError in TagsController#show

can't convert Post into Array

...

app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:8:in `show'
```

tags_controller.rb#show:

```
def show
  @tag = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find(params[:id])
  @posts = Post.paginate(Post.tagged_with(@tag), :page => params[:page], :order => "updated_at DESC") # line 8
  respond_with(@posts)
end
```

What baffles me is that this code works in the posts controller:

def index
    @posts = Post.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => "updated_at DESC"
  end

My post and tag models include:

```
cattr_reader :per_page
@@per_page = 10
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: (full stack trace)

will_paginate (3.0.pre2) lib/will_paginate/collection.rb:134:in `replace'
    will_paginate (3.0.pre2) lib/will_paginate/collection.rb:134:in`replace'
    will_paginate (3.0.pre2) lib/will_paginate/finders/active_record.rb:91:in `wp_query'
    will_paginate (3.0.pre2) lib/will_paginate/finders/base.rb:64:in`block in paginate'
    will_paginate (3.0.pre2) lib/will_paginate/collection.rb:87:in `create'
    will_paginate (3.0.pre2) lib/will_paginate/finders/base.rb:62:in`paginate'
    app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:8:in `show'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in`send_action'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in`process_action'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:435:in`_run__833165888__process_action__116844887__callbacks'
    activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
    activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in`run_callbacks'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`block in process_action'
    activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
    activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in`instrument'
    activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in`process_action'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in`process'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:40:in `process'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:133:in`dispatch'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:173:in`block in action'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in`dispatch'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
    rack-mount (0.6.12) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in`block in call'
    rack-mount (0.6.12) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
    rack-mount (0.6.12) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:89:in`optimized_each'
    rack-mount (0.6.12) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
    rack-mount (0.6.12) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in`call'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:492:in `call'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in`call'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
    rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in`call'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in`call'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:287:in`call'
    activerecord (3.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
    activerecord (3.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in`cache'
    activerecord (3.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
    activerecord (3.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in`call'
    activerecord (3.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `call'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in`block in call'
    activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_call_callbacks'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in`call'
    rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in`call'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:46:in `call'
    railties (3.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in`call'
    rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
    activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in`call'
    rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
    <internal:prelude>:10:in`synchronize'
    rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in`call'
    railties (3.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
    railties (3.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in`method_missing'
    railties (3.0.0) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
    rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in`call'
    rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in`service'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in`block in start_thread'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
@posts = Post.tagged_with(@tag).paginate :page => params[:page], :order => "updated_at DESC"
```

Comment: I thought I had! Thank you theTRON!